# Commands in Docker ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, mpi

Is there a way to execute a command as an argument in a Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT? I am creating an image that should automatically run `mpirun` for the number of processors, i.e., `mpirun -np $(nproc)` or `mpirun -np $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)`.

The following line works:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "mpirun", "-np", "4"] # works
```

But I cannot get an adaptive form to work:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "mpirun", "-np", "$(nproc)"] # doesn't work
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "mpirun", "-np", "$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)"] # doesn't work
```

Using the backtick `nproc` notation does not work either. Nor can I pass an environment variable to the command.

```
ENV processors 4
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "mpirun", "-np", "$processors"] # doesn't work
```

Has anyone managed to get this kind of workflow?

Comment: You might want to create a shell script and start that. You can use ENV variables to control what your shell script does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those likely won't work: see [issue 4783](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4783#issuecomment-38244115)

> `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are special, as they get started without a shell (so you can choose your own) and iirc they are escaped too.
>
> Unlike the shell form, the `exec` form does not invoke a command shell.
>   This means that normal shell processing does not happen.
>
> For example, `ENTRYPOINT [ "echo", "$HOME" ]` will not do variable substitution on `$HOME`.
>   If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: `ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "echo", "$HOME" ]`.

A workaround would be to use a script.

```
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

That script, when docker run triggers it, should at least benefit from the environment variable.

See for example the [Dockerfile of `vromero/activemq-artemis-docker`](https://github.com/vromero/activemq-artemis-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile), which runs the script [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/vromero/activemq-artemis-docker/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh).
In order to allow `CMD` to run as well, the scripts end with:

```
exec "$@"
```

(It will execute whatever parameter comes after, either from the `CMD` directive, or from `docker run` parameters)

---

The [OP Gilly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3903368/gilly) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274454/commands-in-docker-entrypoint/33274491#comment54355754_33274491):

> I use in the Dockerfile:

```
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

> And in the entrypoint script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec mpirun -np $(nproc) "$@"
```

Comment: Yes, this works.

For any who follow, I use in the Dockerfile:
`COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /`
`ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]`

And in the entrypoint script:
`#!/bin/bash`
`exec mpirun -np $(nproc) $@`

Comment: @Gilly Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Added [quotes for "$@"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298177/docker-container-with-entrypoint-variable-expansion-and-cmd-parameters#comment71978397_42332740) in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using the exec form for your entry point and variable substitution will not happen in the exec form.

This is the exec form:

`ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"]`

this is the shell form:

`ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2`

From the official documentation:

> Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, ENTRYPOINT [ "echo", "$HOME" ] will not do variable substitution on $HOME

Comment: This may work for the environment variables, but does not seem to work for me executing the subcommand.