# How do I pass default CMD to ENTRYPOINT with variable expansion?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to use `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` such that `ENTRYPOINT` is the script I am calling and `CMD` provides the default arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT` command but will be overridden by any arguments given to `docker run`.

The part I'm struggling with is how to have environment variable expanded in my default arguments using `CMD`.

For example. Given this dockerfile built as tag `test`:

```
FROM busybox

ENV AVAR=hello
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "exec echo \"$@\""]
CMD ["${AVAR}"]
```

I am expecting the following results:

```
docker run -it --rm test
> hello
docker run -it --rm test world
> world
```

**Note:** I'm just using `echo` here as an example. In my actual Dockerfile I'll be calling `./bin/somescript.sh` which is a script to launch an application I have no control over and is what I am trying to pass arguments to.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298177/docker-container-with-entrypoint-variable-expansion-and-cmd-parameters) is similar but is asking about expanding variables in the `ENTRYPOINT`, I'm trying to expand variables in `CMD`.

I've tried many combinations of [shell/exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) form for both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` but I just can't seem to find the magic combination:

```
FROM busybox

ENV AVAR=hello
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "exec echo \"$@\""]
CMD ${AVAR}

docker run -it --rm test
> -c ${AVAR}
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

[Many more failed attempts](https://gist.github.com/fgreg/e0c32576802526faa601d4c4f2c308bc)

---

This is the closest I can get:

```
FROM busybox

ENV AVAR=hello
ENV AVAR2=world
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo $@", "$@"]
CMD ["${AVAR}", "${AVAR2}"]
```

This works fine when I pass in an argument to the run command:

```
docker run -it --rm test world
> world
```

But it doesn't expand the default arguments when not given a command:

```
docker run -it --rm test
> ${AVAR} ${AVAR2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the magic. I don't completely follow what's going on here but I'll try to explain it

```
FROM busybox

ENV AVAR=hello
ENV AVAR2=world
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo $(eval echo $@)", "$@"]
CMD ["${AVAR}", "${AVAR2}"]

docker run -it --rm test
> hello world
docker run -it --rm test world
> world
```

My attempt at explanation (I'm really not sure if this is right):

`CMD` in exec form is passed as an argument to `ENTRYPOINT` without shell substitution. I'm taking those values and passing them as positional arguments to `/bin/sh -c ...` which is why I need the "extra" "$@" at the end of the `ENTRYPOINT` array.

Within `ENTRYPOINT` I need to expand `$@` and do parameter substitution on the result of the expansion. So in a subshell (`$(...)`) I call `eval` to do parameter substitution and then echo the result which ends up just being the contents of `CMD` but with variables substituted.

If I pass in an argument to `docker run` it simply takes place of `CMD` and is evaluated correctly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your finding. Unfortunately this can't be really used when the ENTRYPOINT is defined in a dependent image you have no control over. This really looks like a limitation of Docker.